# layered navigation isn't populated by collection attributes -- CMS page

Tags: attributes, collection, cms, layered-navigation

I'm attempting to add layered navigation to a CMS page containing a widget that contains a custom product collection (products that are 'new').  Within this widget are fuctions that, given the correct parameters, will filter this collection.  How do I pass this collection to the layered navigation block and have it's attributes show up?

This is how I am calling the layered navigation in the CMS custom layout XML:

```
<reference name="content">
        <!-- Layered Navigation Block -->
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" >
        </block>
</reference>
```

This is how i'm calling the product collection onto the CMS page:

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" show_pager="1" products_count="60" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

This is how i'm generating the product collection in the widgets block:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    $todayStartOfDayDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
        ->setTime('00:00:00')
        ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
    $todayEndOfDayDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
        ->setTime('23:59:59')
        ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
    /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
    $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or' => array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or' => array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
        ), 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            array(
                array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
            )
        )
        ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
        ->setCurPage(1);
    return $collection;
}
```

The widget's template page is a standard practice way to display price, reviews, pictures, etc in a pagesize varient format.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not possible, now with using cms pages and widgets and layout updates at least. Here is why. Magento has 2 layer models. One works if you are in the context of a category and one works when you are in the context of the search results. Your example does not fall in either of these categories. You would need a custom layer model that will handle your collection type (new products).

Comment: I might be able to come up with a solution but this involves writing a custom module, with a custom controller, block and layer model (and maybe others). But before looking for a solution I want to know if this works for you. I mean you will still be able to have an url `www.mysite.com/new-products` but this `new-products` will not be a cms page. It will be handled by a separate controller. And it will contain all the new products, paginated (maybe with sorting options if I find out how). Does this work for you? or you want a simple CMS page solution?

Comment: @Marius that would be a reasonable solution.  I suppose I can insert that solution just as I would a widget onto a cms page, no?

Comment: Not really. The solution I have in mind will create a separate page with a separate controller (some template files maybe). that cannot be changed like a csm page. It will just be there and work :) That's it. It involves creating a new module

Comment: @Marius I see, that may work as well.

Comment: Very helpful @Marius,I have customized eveyrthing to work with AJAX layersand working very nicely , now ,how can we include categories into Layered Navigation like brands and other attributes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Layered navigation needs an active category to work. 
Add the following block to you layout-xml on your cms-pages.

```
<cms_page>
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>2</category_id></action>
    </block>
</cms_page>
```

Comment: Which category ID do you suggest I use?  I'm not using a category to populate the product collection...

Comment: What else do you use to populate your products ?

Comment: As you can see above i'm filtering all products and returning those that are within a certain 'new from' and 'new to' date.

Comment: Yes i see, in this case you must override the    Mage_Catalog_Model__Layer:getProductCollection... i will see what i can do here to provide a solution.

Comment: @easymoden00b Try to add the root category id. And make sure you made 'Is Anchor' to Yes for that category.

Comment: @MagePsycho then the filterable attributes of all products will be available to filter, as i understand the question the filter should only include the products from the widget, please correct me if i'm wrong...

Comment: AFAIK, OP wants global list of new products with layered navigation.

Comment: yes should work with root category, cause the collection has a filter on attribute new. thinking error ..

Comment: @roman204 you are correct roman.  I wanted the filterable attributes of the custom collection.

Comment: Ok then the root category should work.

Comment: @roman204 the layered navigation isn't reflecting the new product collection -- only the unfiltered default category.

Answer (score 28):

As explained in the comments, I don't think there is a way to do this by using the cms pages because you have no layer model associated to the new products list. You only have layer models for the category context and the search context.
My solution (tested and works) involves writing a module that will list all the products marked as new in a page and having a layer model that handles the new products collection.
Here goes. be prepared it's a long one.
I called the extension `StackExchange_NewProducts` but feel free to change the name.
You will need the following files:

`app/etc/modules/StackExchange_NewProducts.xml` - the declaration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_NewProducts>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
        </StackExchange_NewProducts>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_NewProducts>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </StackExchange_NewProducts>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <stackexchange_newproducts>
                <class>StackExchange_NewProducts_Model</class>
            </stackexchange_newproducts>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <stackexchange_newproducts>
                <class>StackExchange_NewProducts_Block</class>
            </stackexchange_newproducts>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <stackexchange_newproducts>
                <class>StackExchange_NewProducts_Helper</class>
            </stackexchange_newproducts>
        </helpers>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_routers> <!-- create a custom router to handle the 'new-products' url -->
                <observers>
                    <stackexchange_newproducts>
                        <class>StackExchange_NewProducts_Controller_Router</class>
                        <method>initControllerRouters</method>
                    </stackexchange_newproducts>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>
        </events>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers> <!-- declare a router -->
            <newproducts>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>StackExchange_NewProducts</module>
                    <frontName>newproducts</frontName>
                </args>
            </newproducts>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <stackexchange_newproducts>
                    <file>stackexchange_newproducts.xml</file>
                </stackexchange_newproducts>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/Controller/Router.php` - the custom router that handles the url `new-products` and maps it to a controller and action

```
<?php
class StackExchange_NewProducts_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract
{
    const NEW_PRODUCTS_URL_KEY = 'new-products';
    public function initControllerRouters($observer)
    {
        $front = $observer->getEvent()->getFront();
        $front->addRouter('stackexchange_newproducts', $this);
        return $this;
    }

    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request)
    {
        if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('install'))
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
        $urlKey = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        if ($urlKey == self::NEW_PRODUCTS_URL_KEY) {
            $request->setModuleName('newproducts')
                ->setControllerName('index')
                ->setActionName('index');
            $request->setAlias(
                Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS,
                $urlKey
            );
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/controllers/IndexController.php` - the actual controller that displays the new products

```
<?php
class StackExchange_NewProducts_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/Helper/Data.php` - the module general helper

```
<?php
class StackExchange_NewProducts_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/stackexchange_newproducts.xml` - the module layout file that defines the content of the page

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <newproducts_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="stackexchange_newproducts/layer_new" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="new_products_container" as="new_products_container" template="stackexchange_newproducts/container.phtml">
                <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="stackexchange_newproducts">
                    <title>New Products</title>
                </action>
                <block type="stackexchange_newproducts/new" name="new_product" as="new_products" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>

    </newproducts_index_index>
</layout>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/Block/New.php` - the block that should render the new products collection:

```
<?php
class StackExchange_NewProducts_Block_New extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function getModuleName()
    {
        return 'Mage_Catalog';
    }
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
            $this->_productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
    public function getLayer()
    {
        $layer = Mage::registry('current_layer');
        if ($layer) {
            return $layer;
        }
        return Mage::getSingleton('stackexchange_newproducts/layer');
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/Block/Layer/New.php` - the layer block that should be displayed on the left side (filters)

```
<?php
class StackExchange_NewProducts_Block_Layer_New extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View
{
    public function getLayer()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('_layer')){
            $layer = Mage::getSingleton('stackexchange_newproducts/layer');
            $this->setData('_layer', $layer);
        }
        return $this->getData('_layer');
    }
    protected function _initBlocks()
    {
        parent::_initBlocks();
        $this->_attributeFilterBlockName    = 'stackexchange_newproducts/layer_filter_attribute';
        $this->_priceFilterBlockName        = 'stackexchange_newproducts/layer_filter_price';
        $this->_decimalFilterBlockName      = 'stackexchange_newproducts/layer_filter_decimal';
    }
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $stateBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_stateBlockName)
            ->setLayer($this->getLayer());
        $this->setChild('layer_state', $stateBlock);

        $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
        foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
                $filterBlockName = $this->_priceFilterBlockName;
            } elseif ($attribute->getBackendType() == 'decimal') {
                $filterBlockName = $this->_decimalFilterBlockName;
            } else {
                $filterBlockName = $this->_attributeFilterBlockName;
            }

            $this->setChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter',
                $this->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)
                    ->setLayer($this->getLayer())
                    ->setAttributeModel($attribute)
                    ->init());
        }

        $this->getLayer()->apply();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

now each attribute type needs a filter block associated to it:

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/Block/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php` - general filter block for attributes

```
<?php 
class StackExchange_NewProducts_Block_Layer_Filter_Attribute extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Attribute
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_filterModelName = 'stackexchange_newproducts/layer_filter_attribute';
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/Block/Layer/Filter/Decimal.php` - filter block for decimal attributes

```
<?php 
class StackExchange_NewProducts_Block_Layer_Filter_Decimal extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Decimal
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_filterModelName = 'stackexchange_newproducts/layer_filter_decimal';
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/Block/Layer/Filter/Price.php` - filter block for price attribute

```
<?php 
class StackExchange_NewProducts_Block_Layer_Filter_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_filterModelName = 'stackexchange_newproducts/layer_filter_price';
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/Model/Layer.php` - the layer model for handling new products

```
<?php
class StackExchange_NewProducts_Model_Layer extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer
{
    public function getStateKey()
    {
        if ($this->_stateKey === null) {
            $this->_stateKey = 'STORE_'.Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
                . '_NEW_PRODUCTS_'
                . '_CUSTGROUP_' . Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        }

        return $this->_stateKey;
    }

    public function getStateTags(array $additionalTags = array())
    {
        $additionalTags = array_merge($additionalTags, array('new_products'));
        return $additionalTags;
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if (isset($this->_productCollections['new_products'])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections['new_products'];
        } else {
            $collection = $this->_getCollection();
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections['new_products'] = $collection;
        }

        return $collection;
    }
    public function prepareProductCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addUrlRewrite();

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _getCollection()
    {
        $todayStartOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('00:00:00')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $todayEndOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('23:59:59')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                    array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                )
            )
            ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc');
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Like each attribute needed a block for filters it also needs a model for handling filters:

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php` - the general attribute filter model

```
<?php 
class StackExchange_NewProducts_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute
{
    protected function _createItem($label, $value, $count = 0)
    {
        return Mage::getModel('stackexchange_newproducts/layer_filter_item')
            ->setFilter($this)
            ->setLabel($label)
            ->setValue($value)
            ->setCount($count);
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/Model/Layer/Filter/Decimal.php`  - the decimal attributes filter model

```
<?php 
class StackExchange_NewProducts_Model_Layer_Filter_Decimal extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute
{
    protected function _createItem($label, $value, $count = 0)
    {
        return Mage::getModel('stackexchange_newproducts/layer_filter_item')
            ->setFilter($this)
            ->setLabel($label)
            ->setValue($value)
            ->setCount($count);
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php` - the price attribute filter model

```
<?php 
class StackExchange_NewProducts_Model_Layer_Filter_Price extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price
{
    protected function _createItem($label, $value, $count = 0)
    {
        return Mage::getModel('stackexchange_newproducts/layer_filter_item')
            ->setFilter($this)
            ->setLabel($label)
            ->setValue($value)
            ->setCount($count);
    }
}
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/NewProducts/Model/Layer/Filter/Item.php` - the filters require a collection of item objects. this is the item object - not sure if this is needed. I think that the default catalog item model can be used.

```
<?php 
class StackExchange_NewProducts_Model_Layer_Filter_Item extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item
{

}
```

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/stackexchange_newproducts/container.phtml` - a template file that acts as a container for the new products so you can set a title and show session messages.

```
<?php if ($this->getTitle()) : ?>
    <div class="page-title category-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></h1>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml();?>
```

That's it. Clear the cache after you create all the files and disable the compilation.
Here is a screenshot of how it looks on my side
[image: screenshot]. (using ce 1.7 with sample data)

Comment: The only thing that is missing is the translation file.

Comment: good module naming there :)

Comment: @DavidManners. Yeah. I don't know where the name came, but it just hit me :). I hope you don't ask for copyright compensations.

Comment: a beer will do ;)

Comment: chair up @Marius – +1votw

Comment: @Marius what is the purpose of the decimal block and model?

Comment: @easymoden00b the model handles the filtering (the `where` section in the query) for a specific value and the block handles the display (values shown, reset link, ....)

Comment: @Marius is there any way I could call this in the layout of the cms page and have that reflect the product collection constructed within a widget?

Comment: not that I know of. But it looks like your problem was solved using roman's answer.

Comment: @Marius unfortunately the layered navigation reflects to default category, instead of, like I thought, the refined custom category.

Comment: @Marius perfect ... I want to ask will this tweak for magento 1.9.2.3 ... I am using Amasty extension .. can I use your script to create sale page ...

Comment: I don't know. You can try it. All the code is there

Comment: @Marius thanks for your reply ... Yes I tried and it is working now ... I want to ask how I will change the attribute phtml, don't know from where you injected catalog/layer/filter.phtml, I want to change it with amasty/amshopby/attribute.phtml ... could you please help me!

Comment: I am receiving this error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.news_from_date' in 'where clause'`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: make the attribute `news_from_date` to be used in product listing.

Comment: @Marius Yes it is already set to be used in product listing. It looks like this doesn't works in EE 1.13.x version. I tested in community 1.9.x and it worked except layered nav breaks on `<?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>` (in `catalog/layered/view.phtml`). Any suggestion to get it work in EE?

Comment: @Marius this works perfectly when flat catalog is disabled - when flat catalog is enabled we get the `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.news_from_date' in 'where clause'`

Comment: make the attribute news_from_date to be used in product listing.

Comment: @Marius the attribute was already set to be used in product listing.
Also, how come your config.xml doesn't have rewrites for the core models that you're extending?

Comment: I will check to see the problem when I have sime time. And i dont have xml rewrites because I am not rewritting anything. I am just extending sime core classes and use the ones i created in my module but the core modules still use the core classes.

Comment: @Marius thanks! I also added some code for the category filter block in case you want to stick that in as well :)